# How can I show one window on top of the other windows opened

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a custom element named memory-game and I am able to create lots of them by clicking on the icon of the memory game. I want functionality so that when I click on a memory-game window, it appears on top of the other opened windows. I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: also you could look up "modal windows" that would create an elegant and functional solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `z-index` to control what order non-statically positioned divs appear on the page. 
Aside from that, I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with the code you have provided.